# making a double bar graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar graph to show two bars for each city: one bar that shows the money donated to supporters of a political campaign, and a second that shows money donated by the opponents of the campaign.

Here's the data:

```
city <- c("Del Mar","Solana Beach","Encinitas")
opponents <- c(30046,4551,24591)
supporters <- c(7200,550,5775)

recall_contribs <- data.frame(city,opponents,supporters)
```

And here's what I started with and have been trying to add to, but not sure if this is the best approach. Are there any simple tweaks I can make?

```
ggplot(recall_contribs, aes(city,opponents)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = city), position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

recall_contribs %>%
  pivot_longer(opponents:supporters, names_to = "donator", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(city, value, fill = donator)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]